# Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR >> TypeError: grunt.initconfig is not a function

Tags: uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I can't find where the mistake was

gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.initconfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    uglify:{
        t1:{
            files:{
                'dest/success.min.js' : ['js/one.js' ,'js/two.js'] 
            }

        }
    }
});

};
```

This is the error that am getting on running -  grunt uglify:t1

```
Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: grunt.initconfig is not a function

Running "uglify:t1" (uglify) task
Verifying property uglify.t1 exists in config...ERROR
>> Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "uglify.t1" missing. Use --force to 
continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case sensitive, so initconfig does not exist, try initConfig

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    uglify:{
       t1:{
            files:{
               'dest/success.min.js' : ['js/one.js' ,'js/two.js'] 
            }

        }
    }
});

};
```